# replace all instances of letters in the alphabet with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the english alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I have another alphabet:

```
ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow
```

If i have a string. I want to replace every character with the equivalent in the new alphabet.

So if the string was abcde the new string would be yplta.

I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/KvFCr/10/

but not got very far and dont even know if this is the best way to do it. Is there a better way achieve what I want using jquery and javascript?

Comment: well you are comparing a lowercase letter with an uppercase letter. That would be problem one.

Comment: good point, updated link

Comment: No lol...just a little project for fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var alphabet1  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var alphabet2  = "ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow";
var message    = "encodethismessage".toLowerCase();

alert(encode(message,alphabet1,alphabet2));

function encode(message, alphabet1, alphabet2) {
    var newMessage = "";
    messageArr = message.split('');
    for(i in messageArr) {
        index = alphabet1.search(messageArr[i]);
        newMessage += alphabet2[index];
    }
    return newMessage;
}
```

you have to be careful because you don't want to ever touch a character that you have already converted. For example if you replace all 'a' then all 'b' etc. you will not get the correct result.  This should work because it converts each character and not each character class.

just want to warn you that substitution cyphers are not secure because there are easy cypher text only attacks on them so don't use this for anything where security is the goal.

Comment: This works, but your message.split("") is missing empty quotes inside :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var alpha1  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var alpha2  = "ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow";
var str = "abcde";
var newstr = '';
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    charPos = alpha1.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
    newstr += alpha2.charAt(charPos);
}
​console.log(newstr);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KvFCr/11/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function as argument to `string.replace`.

```js
var s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(str, p1, p2, offset, s) {
    var translate_table = {
        'A': 'Y',
        'B': 'P',
        'C': 'L',
        'D': 'T',
        'E': 'A',
        'F': 'V',
        'G': 'K',
        'H': 'R',
        'I': 'E',
        'J': 'Z',
        'K': 'G',
        'L': 'M',
        'M': 'S',
        'N': 'H',
        'O': 'U',
        'P': 'B',
        'Q': 'X',
        'R': 'N',
        'S': 'C',
        'T': 'D',
        'U': 'I',
        'V': 'J',
        'W': 'F',
        'X': 'Q',
        'Y': 'O',
        'Z': 'W'
    };
    return translate_table[str];
});

alert(s);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GjG3H/